# Show UITableView after UIButton was tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that i would like to hide until the user taps the button `searchButtonTapped`. (I'm also using this button as an `IBAction`.)

Originally i'm hiding the table view as you see in the `viewDidLoad`, and i wanna show it after the button was tapped, but it does not shown up after i tap the search button. Do i missed something? For me, it seems it should be work properly, after the button was tapped i refresh the table view.

my .h file

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *searchButtonTapped;
- (IBAction)searchButton:(id)sender;
```

.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

      self.tableView.hidden = YES;
}


- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    if (sender == self.searchButtonTapped) {
     self.tableView.hidden = NO;
      [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}



- (IBAction)searchButton:(id)sender {

      [self searchSetup];
}
```

Comment: what is the "self.searchButtonTapped"?

Comment: @DaSilva searchButtonTapped is a property, it's the first line of the code.

Comment: do you have more than one button has target to the method "buttonTapped:(id)sender"??

Comment: @DaSilva no, i'm using only one button in the whole view.

Comment: you can remove the if statement since only one button will call that method, however it should be working... if you remove the   `self.tableView.hidden = YES;`in the viewDidLoad the table is shown?

Comment: @DaSilva Yes, it shown, i removed the statement and put a log into the buttonTapped: and nothing appears in the console, so here is the problem. I think it's doesn't gets called.

Comment: did you make the connection of the UIButton in the storyboard/xib file to the IBOutlet and also to the IBAction?

Comment: @DaSilva yes. everything is connected from the interface builder.

Comment: `[self.searchButtonTapped addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]`, just add this line of code in the viewDidLoad, and try if anything change

Comment: @DaSilva , it's working, thanks! please add an answer that i can accept.

Comment: se my answer bellow to a better explanation of your problem

Comment: I just want to point out that your naming is atrocious. You have a button (a thing) with a verb as a name ("searchButtonTapped"). You have an IBAction (code that executes) with a noun ("searchButton") as a name. Then you have a third method, "buttonTapped", which is probably a verb and seems like an IBAction, but it's not declared as an action. I don't know how it gets called. Don't **DO THAT!**  It makes my head hurt trying to look at it, and 6 months from now if you come back to this code you will be as lost as your readers are now.

Comment: Thank you @DuncanC, good advices. I will change it, but first it was easier for me to do that way. However you have absolutely right and it's a bad habit, that i need to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have declared only one IBAction, which is for the method `searchButton`.

This method call the searchSetup´s method. What is the purpose of it?

```
- (IBAction)searchButton:(id)sender {

      [self searchSetup];
}
```

So you must have another IBAction for *buttonTapped* method witch is currently a "void" method and not a IBAction. Or you make that connection from the storyBoard, or you must declare it programaticly like:

```
[self.searchButtonTapped addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to tell from the little bit of code that you posted. Add NSLog statements in your buttonTapped method that show entering the method, entering the **if** statement, the value of searchButtonTapped, and the value of self.tableView.

Then you can tell if the method is getting called, if the if statement is evaluating as true, and if the table view is non-nil. One of those things is likely to be the cause of your problem.

I'm guessing that the if statement is wrong. what type is the property self.searchButtonTapped? Post the code that declares that property.

Based on the name I would guess that searchButtonTapped is a boolean?

Comment: Duncan, `searchButtonTapped` is a property(with a dummy name), it's the first line of the code. I think it's really possible that you have right, and the if statement is wrong. I wasn't sure that it will work with the property/or it will recognize the tap.

Comment: I've added a log into the buttonTapped: method and nothing shown up in the console, so it's sure that the problem is here.

Comment: You have a broken IBOutlet link. Go into your XIB/Storyboard and check the connection between your button and IBOutlet.